# MySQL won't let me insert more than 10 digits using datatype INT

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to to fill a field with 11 numbers, but MySQL won't let me insert more than 10 digits using datatype INT. I can insert only up to 10 digits. This is the error:

```
ERROR 1264: Out of range value for column 'cpf' at row 1
SQL Statement:
UPDATE `mercado`.`cliente` SET `cpf`=12345678901 WHERE `cpf`='20'
```

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of data type limit. The range of datatype `INT` only from `-2147483648` to `2147483647`. You can use datatype `BIGINT` instead of. But i think the best way if you working with very big number is use a text datatype (like `VARCHAR`). If you need number for calculating, just convert it.

Answer (score 2):

The `INT` type columns you have limit from `-2147483648` to `2147483647`. 
If you want to enter values outside of the above range then use `BIGINT`.

Comment: You cannot insert 9,999,999,999 into a `INT` column.

Comment: Actually it's a signed 32-bit number, not a 10-digit decimal number.

Answer (score 1):

See the [MySQL datatype documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html).  The maximum value of an `INT` is 2,147,483,647, which happens to contain 10 digits.